# Load multiple Javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have three Javascript script that I need to load -

- `imagesLoaded.js`
- `lazyload-1.8.4.js`
- and `cd.js`

`cd.js` contains my functions that use `imagesLoaded.js` and `lazyload-1.8.4.js`.

Do load them altogether or separately?

```
function add_my_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'imagesLoaded',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesLoaded.js', 
    array('jquery'),
    'lazyload',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyload-1.8.4.js',
    array('jquery'),
    'cd',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cd.js',
    array('jquery')                     
  );
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

---

### Code that Worked

```
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

            function add_my_script() {
                wp_register_script('imagesLoaded',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesLoaded.js', array('jquery'),true);
                wp_register_script('lazyload',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyload-1.8.4.js', array('jquery'),true);
                wp_register_script('cd',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cd.js', array('jquery','imagesLoaded','lazyload'),true);
                wp_enqueue_script('imagesLoaded');
                wp_enqueue_script('lazyload');
                wp_enqueue_script('cd');
            }
```

Comment: You can remove the two enqueues before `cd` because they are registered dependancies for that enqueue. Also, are you intending for these scripts to be loaded for every page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I formatted that code as best I could, and once formatted it is obviously very broken. [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) takes 5 parameters. You have 9. And several of the first five are wrong. I expect that you would see errors if you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

You seem to be trying to enqueue all of your scripts in the same `wp_enqueue_script`. You can't do that. Perhaps that is what you are asking, but the question isn't terribly clear.

```
function add_my_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'imagesLoaded',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesLoaded.js', 
    array('jquery')
  );
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'lazyload',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyload-1.8.4.js',
    array('jquery')
  );
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'cd',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cd.js',
    array('jquery','imagesLoaded','lazyload')                     
  );
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

I also added `imagesloaded` and `lazyload` as dependencies for `cd`, which I think is correct. I don't know if `imagesloaded` is dependent upon `lazyload` or the other way around but if you are going to register/enqueue (as you should) then make proper use of the dependency juggling. That is one of the best things about the system.

Comment: s_ha_dum thanks for your reply, my first attempt was a disaster. Your code broke my page but I got it working with the update - Code that Worked in a first post

Comment: Syntax error. Fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry still broken for me. Is there anything wrong with the way i got it working?

Comment: Ok... one of your scripts had a camel-case name so the dependency didn't work. `Camel-case === horrific idea` (imho) especially with letters like `L` and especially when not used consistently. Tested, the scripts do load.

Comment: Scripts need to registered to ensure they work correctly as dependancies don't they? I'm not sure an enqueue counts as a registered script, much like how you're required to register a handle for scripts you call localize on. I may be wrong of course..

Comment: @t3los : If you look at the source, [`wp_enqueue_script` runs `$wp_scripts->add`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L136) just like [`wp_register_script` does](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L61). They should be equivalent as far as dependency handling goes (as best I can tell).

Answer (score 5):

As a corollary to @s_ha_dum's answer, you could also *register* scripts with hierarchically declared dependencies, and then just *enqueue* your ultimate script. Something like so:

```
function add_my_script() {

    // Register first script, dependent on jQuery
     wp_register_script(
         'imagesLoaded',
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesLoaded.js', 
         array( 'jquery' )
     );

    // Register second script, dependent on first script
     wp_register_script(
         'lazyload',
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyload-1.8.4.js',
         array( 'imagesLoaded' )
      );

    // Enqueue third script, dependent on second script
     wp_enqueue_script(
         'cd',
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cd.js',
         array( 'lazyload' )                     
     );
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Functionally, it really makes no difference; it's mostly a matter of preference. I like to declare all dependencies explicitly for each script, but this method is a bit more shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrArr = [
    [ get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesLoaded.js',false],
    [ get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyload-1.8.4.js',true],
    [ get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cd.js',true]
];

var scrArrSrl = []; // js Serial   Load Array
var scrArrPrl = []; // js Parallel Load Array

while (scrArr.length) {
    var scrArrEl = scrArr.shift();
    if (scrArrEl[1]) {
        scrArrSrl.push(scrArrEl[0]);
    } else {
        scrArrPrl.push(scrArrEl[0]);
    }
}

creScrSrl = function(src,id,par,typ) {
    id = id || src.split('/').pop().split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.');
    var newScr = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!newScr) {
        newScr = document.createElement('script');
        newScr.id=id;
        if (!!typ) {newScr.type = typ};
        newScr.src = src;
        par = par || document.head;
        newScr.onload = function () {
            if (scrArrSrl.length) {creScrSrl(scrArrSrl.shift())}
        }
        par.appendChild(newScr);
    } 
}

creScrPrl = function(src,id,par,typ) {
    id = id || src.split('/').pop().split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.');
    var newScr = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!newScr) {
        newScr = document.createElement('script');
        newScr.id=id;
        if (!!typ) {newScr.type = typ};
        newScr.src = src;
        par = par || document.head;
        par.appendChild(newScr);
    } 
}

creScrSrl(scrArrSrl.shift());

while (scrArrPrl.length) {creScrPrl(scrArrPrl.shift())}
```

In my case, `cd.js` will wait till `lazyload-1.8.4.js` loaded. But, `lazyload-1.8.4.js` won't wait for `imagesLoaded.js` load. So, `cd.js` won't wait for `imagesLoaded.js` too, because there is no chain between them.

I use this in my code, it works but not so fast.

[onLoadInit.js File in GitHub](https://rawgit.com/SyzraelGithub/Today16/master/onLoadInit.js)
, i use the same logic.

[image: Timeline for Performance]

If you need more speed, I think you should use Promise, CustomEvent

Comment: Where is this `get_template_directory_uri()` comes from? I know the from WordPress PHP code base but not from JavaScript.

Comment: if you google it, you see this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

Comment: Yes but your code sample is JavaScript. There's no function like this in JC, if I remember correctly.

Comment: What is JC? I didn't know..

Comment: I meant JS as abbreviation for JavaScript. Just a typo.